# Which header should be used X-Forwarded-For or Forwarded?

Tags: http, load-balancing, reverse-proxy

There are two headers to handle request forwarding. First is [X-Forwarded-For](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Forwarded-For) and second is [Forwarded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Forwarded).

Which one should I use? X-Forwarded-For is a de-facto whereas `Forwarded` is an RFC-7239 standard.

There are no specific guidelines in the specification and I could not observe any general trend about this in the web development scope.

Comment: curious, which one did you use, in the end? was my answer of some use?

Answer (score 2):

It seems nobody is interested in `Forwarded`, still not in 2019. I would use it, but it's hard, as many tools and frameworks lack support...for example, today, the Django Framework ([issue and discussion here](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/30729)) is still using `X-Forwarded-XY` headers, to detect original IP/Host, etc. And there is no hurry ;-)

In the long term, `Forwarded` will probably be adopted and the new standard, so, if you can, go with it. I would.